# how to remove default white space on web page?

Tags: html, css, navbar

if I'm doing something like in the picture
[see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5K36.png).....how can I remove the white space area and start my web page from the beginning?
I tried manipulating margin and padding properties but it didn't work!!
thanks in advance

```css
nav{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0 ;
    padding: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Inspect the element(s) and see what CSS styles are applied and then override them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the markup in your question, preferably in a working code snippet..

Comment: try to put a code and show us what u did unless we will keep guessing

Comment: I edited the question with the css code for the navbar

Comment: We still can not know what white-space you mean. For example margin-down is not 0 here.. but other CSS and HTML elements might affect it. You can right-click the nav bar and inspect element to see where the white-space comes from.

Comment: by white space I mean the empty area surrounding the navbar .....how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I think the general solution for this is to use some reset.css which removes all the default styling that browsers by default add to the web page elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always add this at the beginning of your css this will remove all the bydefault margin and padding

```
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset margins and paddings with:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```